# Configuration of the branch locus of  a branched covering of an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Let $C$ be a curve of genus 3 and suppose that it admits a branched cover $\varphi:C\rightarrow E$ with $E$ elliptic and such that $\varphi$ does not factor through any \' etale cover. Then the degree of the ramification  divisor $R$ is $4$ and the branch divisor $B\subseteq E$ is supported in a set of cardinality between 1 and 4. I wonder if all 4 hypothesis are possible and given a branch locus, which is the minimun degree for which it can be achieved.
Obviously if $B$ is supported on 4 point I can take a double cover ramified on 4 point.
Let us suppose that $B$ is supported on 3 point. Then if I understood well the theory, the existence of a branched covering of degree $n$ such as mine is equivalent to the existence of a primitive, transitive subgroup of $S_n$ generated by 5 element $a,b,g_1,g_2,g_3$ such that $[a,b]g_1g_2g_3=\mathrm{id}$. Is this correct? Does this groupo exist? for which $n$?
If the above is correct then I have also to find a primitive transitive subgroup of $S_n$ 
generated by $a,b,g_1, g_2$ satisfying $[a,b]g_1g_2=\mathrm{id}$. And finally I would need a primitive transitive subgroup of $S_n$ generated by three element with relation $[ab]g=\mathrm{id}$.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your tuples of permutations indeed describe coverings of an elliptic curve with branch locus of size $3$, $2$, or $1$, respectively.

However, the requirement that the curve $C$ has genus $3$ puts further restrictions on the elements $g_i$ (via Riemann-Hurwitz).

Comment: Ok! Now I understand why it seemed to me I had to few conditions.
Which condition do I need to add?  Might them be, for example, if $B$ has cardinality 1
- $g^2=1$ if over $B$ I have two double points?
- $g^5=1$ if over $B$ I have one quintuple point?
Could you give me example/references. Mine just explain how to recover Hurwitz formula and it is kind of useless in my case.

Comment: Look e.g. at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Hurwitz_formula.
The ramification indices $e_P$ there are the cycle lengths appearing in the permutations $g_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Still I do not get how I can exclude some configuration of $B$. For example I would like to see if the ramification divisor can be supported on one point The ramification supported on 1 point implies that the branched divisor is supported on one point and whose counter image is a quintuple point. With the info I have I find it difficult to see, for example, if there exist or not an $n\ge 5$ such that $S_n$ has a prim. trans. subgroup generated by 3 elements $a,b,g$ with $g$ a 5-cycle and [ab]g=e$. Being the base elliptic I do not have info on $n$...


Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Sofia's and my comments to the original question, we look for instance for elements $a,b\in S_n$ which generate a primitive subgroup of $S_n$ and where the commutator $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ is a $5$-cycle.

This is possible for each $n\ge5$: Set $a=(1,2\,3,\cdots,n)$, $b=(1,2,\cdots,n-4,n-3,n-1,n-2)$. Then $[a,b]=(1,2,n-2,n-1,n)$. Note that in this computation, I use the right action of the symmetric group.

Note that $a$ is an $n$--cycle, so $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ is transitive. Furthermore, $b$ is an $(n-1)$-cycle, so $G$ is doubly transitive and hence primitive. Actually, it is not difficult to show that even $G=S_n$.

So this is an example for a branch locus of size $1$. The size $2$ can be obtained by replacing the $5$-cycle $g_1$ by two $3$-cycles $h_1$, $h_2$ with $g_1=h_1h_2$. The branch locus of size $3$ or $4$ will be obtained by further splitting up $h_1$ or $h_1$ and $h_2$ into a product of two transpositions.

The cases of $2$, $3$ and $4$ branch points however can be realized with smaller degrees, namely $n=3$ for $2$ and $3$ branch points, and $n=2$ for $4$ branch points. These are the minimal degrees.

Answer (score 3):

It is often easier to construct *Galois* covers of degree $n$.

In the case where $E$ is an elliptic curve and we have $t$ branch points, by Riemann existence theorem a Galois cover with Galois group $G$ is defined by the following data:

$\bullet$ a finite group $G$ of order $n$;

$\bullet$ elements $a, b, g_1, \ldots, g_t$ such that $G= \langle a, b, g_1, \ldots, g_t \rangle$ and $[a,b]g_1g_2 \ldots g_t=e$.

An important remark is that for a Galois cover the local monodromies around points in the same fibre are *conjugate* transpositions, i.e. points over the same branch points have monodromies with the same cyclic structure (this is in general false for non-Galois covers). Moreover, over the branch point $b_i$ such a structure is a cycle of order equal to the order of the element $g_i$.

Let us see now how to construct Galois coverings in the cases you are interested in.

**Three branch points, that is $t=3$**. For each $n$ we can construct a cyclic cover of degree $n$: simply choose $$G=\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}=\langle x | x^n=1 \rangle $$ (I use the multiplicative notation) and take $$a=x, \quad b=x, \quad  g_1=x, \quad g_2=x, \quad g_3=x^{-2}.$$

**Two branch points, that is $t=2.$** Again, we have a cyclic cover for any $n$. Choose $G$ as above and take $$a=x, \quad b=x, \quad  g_1=x, \quad g_2=x^{-1}$$.

**One branch point, that is $t=1.$** A moment of reflection shows that we cannot take $G$ abelian in this case, otherwise $[a,b]g_1=e$ implies $g_1=e$, that is the cover would be unramified, contradiction. We can however construct a *dihedral* cover of degree $n=2m$
 for any $m$. In fact, set $$D_{2m}= \langle x, y | x^2=y^m=1, \quad xy=y^{-1}x \rangle$$ 
and take $$a=x, \quad b=y, \quad g_1=y^2.$$

regarding your last comment, observe that when $m=5$ you have a Galois cover of degree $10$ with a unique branch point, whose branching order is $5$. In other words, over the unique branch point $b$ one has precisely two points $q_1, q_2$ and the local monodromy around each of the $q_i$ is by construction a $5$-cycle.

One can also construct Galois covers of odd degree with a unique branch point, for instance taking more general metacyclic groups (i.e. non-trivial semidirect products  of cyclic groups). The dihedral covers are in fact a particular case of this construction.

**Remark.** I misread the question and I did not see the assumption that the covers must be of genus $3$. Only few of my constructions give genus $3$ curves (actually, it is not difficult to find all of them by using Hurwitz formula).

I will leave the answer anyway, since maybe it can be useful for other pourposes.

Comment: The OP is looking for a genus 3 curve. I don't think you can get it with your construction for  $t=3$. 

Comment: Oops, you are right, I misread the question. Ok, I will leave the answer anyway. It could be useful for other pourposes...Thank you! 